# Angular 8 : Get the value from a text input which preserves line breaks and tabs

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8

I have a requirement for copying multiple values from notepad(which contains line breaks) and excel(tabs) and paste it to an angular text input (text field/ text area). When getting the value, it should preserve line breaks and tabs. Gone through similar questions from here, but none of them worked for me.

In html,

```
<textarea type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" (keyup.enter)="addItem()"></textarea>
```

In ts,

```
  addItem() {
    if(this.value){
      let valueArray: string[] = this.value.split('\\n')
      console.log(valueArray);
    }
  }
```

Is there any simple ways to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try this with just simple "\n". I think it should work, at least theoretically.

Comment: It doesn't work since the value is getting as a string. \n will be replaced by a space in value string.

Comment: it is working here:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kbupyz?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Yes it worked. I used `let valueArray: string[] = this.value.split(/\n|\r|\t/g);`